# How to tell the control if the button of the view is dis/enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my view I have this button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" disabled="disabled" id="btnDelete"  name="btnDelete" />
```

and I have Jquery method which makes it enabled.

This is in the view.

How to check if the button is enabled or disabled in the controller?

I have this method:

```
public void MyMethod(FormCollection form)
{...}
```

but form doesn't contain anything about the button.

also, form["btnDelete"] is null.

Comment: button values dont get posted... you want to add a hidden field for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because input button can  not hold any value and returning it is useless.

If you want to have that attribute value in your controller make a hidden input which hold the button value on page load and will be changed on btnDelete click event.